# Off WARN logs of a class

Tags: java

How can i off the warn logs of a particular `class(com.service.infra)` in my `log4j.properties`.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,QuietAppender,SilentAppender,LoudAppender
log4j.appender.QuietAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.File=/Log/front-log
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n


log4j.appender.SilentAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.File=/par/info,infoLog
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-3p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Here, i want to turn off warn logs in my info log file **/par/info,infoLog**, But for warn log file it should be logged to a file **/Log/front-log**

Comment: What is the priority level u have set here?

Comment: btw, INFO logs everything, so for a SilentAdapter, shouldnt you set the treshold to FATAL?

Comment: NO, actually, i am trying to read a INFo log file with out WARN logs. Is there a way to do that. I tried this one, But no luck log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.stdout.filter.filter1.levelMax=INFO

Answer (score 1):

set the level of the logger for your class:

```
log4j.logger.com.service.infra=ERROR,QuietAppender
```

this will log only ERROR and up for your class

Comment: But, in my warn file i want the warn logs. And in my info file warn logs should not be logged.

Comment: set the Threshold on the appenders what level you want to log to what file, set the level on a class to limit what that class logs

Comment: For the threshold=Info, i want to disable WARN logs. But when i try to disable WARN logs like giving log4j.logger.com.service.infra=OFF. It is not working

Comment: The order is FATAL, ERROR, WARN, DEBUG, INFO, TRACE. when you set a level or threshold it doesn't log anything for the levels below.

for instance it you set the level/threshold to WARN, it will only log WARN, ERROR, FATAL

Answer (score 0):

In the configuration above.. set `threshold=ERROR` , this will only limit the logging to ERROR level and wont include any levels below this in the log, i.e. WARN,DEBUG,INFO etc..

```
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.Threshold=WARN
```

Comment: But, in my warn file i want the warn logs. And in my info file warn logs should not be logged.

Answer (score 0):

This is achieved by using the following code

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,LoudAppender
log4j.logger.com.service.infra.inf=INFO,SilentAppender
log4j.logger.com.service.infra._warn=WARN,QuietAppender


log4j.appender.QuietAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.Threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.File=/Log/front-log
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.QuietAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %m%n

log4j.appender.SilentAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.File=/par/info,infoLog
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SilentAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-3p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.LoudAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.File=/Log/debugLog
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.DatePattern='.'dd-MM-yy
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LoudAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yy kk:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%t] %x (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference [Log4j Log Level](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).
Here example for that. Warnning log of `Class3` will be off because of Log Level is used `ERROR` .

log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="APPLICATION" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="/ACE-MRBS/application.log"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} |%5p| [%c] | %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="your.app.test.Class1" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="your.app.test.Class2" additivity="false">
        <level value="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </logger>
    <logger name="your.app.test.Class3" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
    </logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```